# Using sympy to transform PDE from cartesian to cylindrical coordinates

Tags: python, sympy

I want to use sympy to transform PDEs from cartesian to cylindrical coordinates. As a simple example I tried finding a representation of the continuity equation for mass conservation in cylindrical coordinates.

Looking into the documentation, I found the sympy.vector module that seems to offer a way to specify coordinate systems and transformations, but I can't figure out how to use it to solve my problem.

My starting point is something like this:

```
import numpy as np
import sympy as sp
from sympy.vector import CoordSys3D
sp.init_printing(use_unicode=True)

A = CoordSys3D("Cartesian")
C = CoordSys3D("Cylindrical", transformation="cylindrical", variable_names=("r", "theta", "z"))

u = sp.Function("u")(A.x, A.y, A.z)
v = sp.Function("v")(A.x, A.y, A.z)
w = sp.Function("w")(A.x, A.y, A.z)

ur = sp.Function("u_r")(C.r, C.theta, C.z)
ut = sp.Function("u_theta")(C.r, C.theta, C.z)
uz = sp.Function("u_z")(C.r, C.theta, C.z)

continuity = sp.Eq(u.diff(A.x) + v.diff(A.y) + w.diff(A.z))
```

But what is the next step?